# How do I extract the daysBitArray in this JSON data using SQL. Pay attention to the image

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

IMAGE OF JSON DATA:

[image: IMAGE OF JSON DATA]

This image will let you see the structure of the JSON data. I have been using this query:

```
SELECT
 JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(response,'$.data.menuMapping[0].menuStructures."26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705".menus.regularHours[0].daysBitArray') AS daysBitArray,
JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(response,'$.data.menuMapping[0].menuStructures."26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705".menus.regularHours[0].hours') AS hours
FROM arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours;
```

However, the results end up being null. why? What am I doing wrong?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(response, '$.data.menuMapping[0].menuStructures."26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705".menus.regularHours[0].daysBitArray') AS daysBitArray,
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(response, '$.data.menuMapping[0].menuStructures."26bd579e-5664-4f0a-8465-2f5eb5fbe705".menus.regularHours[0].hours') AS hours
FROM arboreal-vision-339901.take_home_v2.virtual_kitchen_ubereats_hours;
```

I was expecting the data under the `daysBitArray` in the image above. But instead I get null, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Pay attention to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.